How to calculate load average is high or normal?
How to define/find some x.x value is high load by lokkin into uptime in linux server if i've 4 cpus?
Is there any formula to calculate?
CPU(s):                   4
  On-line CPU(s) list:    0-3
Vendor ID:                GenuineIntel
  Model name:             Intel(R) Xeon(R) Platinum 8259CL CPU @ 2.50GHz
    CPU family:           6
    Model:                85
    Thread(s) per core:   2
    Core(s) per socket:   2
    Socket(s):            1
    Stepping:             7

$ uptime
 14:01:38 up 15 min,  2 users,  load average: 7.09, 3.44, 1.96

Current load average is high. But still server is working fine.
$ uptime
 14:39:50 up 53 min,  5 users,  load average: 31.95, 29.13, 24.25

Output of vmstat
$ vmstat 1 3
procs -----------memory---------- ---swap-- -----io---- -system-- ------cpu-----
 r  b   swpd   free   buff  cache   si   so    bi    bo   in   cs us sy id wa st
16  0      0 15798924   2168 189096    0    0   329    25  103  117 62  1 37  0  0
16  0      0 15798924   2168 189096    0    0     0     0  405  433 100  0  0  0  0
16  0      0 15798924   2168 189096    0    0     0     0  408  441 100  0  0  0  0

I've see few link. However i couldn't understand.

What values are good/bad depends on how the server is used. One server can have problems if the load goes much above 1, another can be fine with a load of 30-40.

It's a per-system choice. YMMV. This sounds like an XY problem. What are trying to do with this information?

Relevant: https://serverfault.com/questions/771233/how-can-i-choose-a-max-load-threshold-depending-on-the-number-of-available-cores

As others mentioned above load is subjective, are you seeing any performance degradation or any alerts in monitoring system due to "high load", if it has a pattern check for what is causing load by using tools like atop  / top
If the server is always running on high load, you may need to tune it or add more hardware resources.

Based on the vmstat output I would say this is fully loaded system. You have 4*2*2 threads and 16 running processes. The usage of the processors is 100% (from user part). I see good amount of free memory, no I/O operations, no context switching, no interrupts.
So the system (on the whole) is not utilized but the processors are 100% used with user's processes.
If you see more than 16 processes running (first column) you will have some blocked processes (second column).
For me this is fully loaded system with very specific program.
